# What does "type name requires a specifier or qualifier" mean?

Tags: c

So I'm new to C and I'm trying to implement a cart via a linked list as follows.

```
typedef struct {
  char *name;
  int count;
  struct node *next;
} item;


struct cart {
  item *curr, *head;
  head = NULL;

};
```

When I go to compile though, I get the following errors:

```
ceasarb@ampersand:~> clang shopper.c 
shopper.c:14:3: error: type name requires a specifier or qualifier
  head = NULL;
  ^
shopper.c:14:3: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
  head = NULL;
  ^~~~
shopper.c:14:3: error: duplicate member 'head'
shopper.c:13:16: note: previous declaration is here
  item *curr, *head;
               ^
shopper.c:14:7: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
  head = NULL;
      ^
      ;
```

I'm guessing the root of the problem is

```
 type name requires a specifier or qualifier
```

But I can't figure out what that means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignments are not allowed within a `struct` definition, this is your problem.

In order to initialise `head` to `NULL`, you should declare an instance of that `struct` and use the appropriate initialiser:

```
struct cart {
  item *curr, *head;
} sample_cart = {
  NULL, NULL,
};
```

The `head` and `curr` fields of `sample_cart` are now both `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you what you have written (`head = NULL;`) is not valid in the context in which you wrote it (the definition of a `struct`). You can only define what your `struct` contains, and not initialize it by assignment.

The best you can do portably is create your struct with

```
struct cart my_cart = { NULL, NULL };
```

in which the `NULL`s initialize struct members in order of appearance in the struct definition (first `NULL` is assigned to `curr`, second one to `head`).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign to `head`. `head` is not an object: it is the name of a member of a structure.

What you can do (outside the struct definiton) is assign to the `head` part of an object of type `struct cart`

```
struct cart object;
object.head = NULL;
```

or, in C99, initialize that member with a value

```
struct cart object = { .head = NULL };
```